# Columns order not preserved after reading spark Json file

Tags: python, json, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read a json file using **`spark.read.json("<path>")`** but the column order is getting sorted by spark by default.

There are alot of **nested columns/new columns** getting added frequently to the schema and I can't define the schema for all the columns.

Is there any way where we can **`preserve column order`** while reading **`spark.read.json`** without defining schema *manually*?

**`Example:`**

```
json_str="""{"zip":"a","address":{"state":"la","pin":"1234","city":"go"},"street":"bar","building":"123"}"""

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json_str])).printSchema()
#root
# |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- pin: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
# |-- building: string (nullable = true)
# |-- street: string (nullable = true)
# |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see **`zip`** is **`first key`** in the source json string but Spark keeping the column as **last** one.

I tried of using `schema_of_json` and still column order is not preserving:

```
spark.sql("""select schema_of_json('{"zip":"a","address":{"state":"la","pin":"1234","city":"go"},"street":"bar","building":"123"}') as json_schema""").show(10,False)
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|json_schema                                                                                         |
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|struct<address:struct<city:string,pin:string,state:string>,building:string,street:string,zip:string>|
#+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please let me know if there any way we can **`preserve`** the order **`without defining the schema manually`**?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're not passing schema to `spark.read.json`, Spark would take a sample from your JSON file and infer schema from it. How about you do the same thing manually to extract the schema dynamically, then use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use select to define the order

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json_str]))
df.select("zip","address".....).show()
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, Yes we can do `.select`  But as mentioned in the question, I was looking for preserving order without manually including the schema!

Comment: Ah, ok. My guess is there's probably a way to do what you want but it's not worth the effort.